# OpenCV for Android - initialize Matrix

Tags: android, opencv

I'd like to initialize a 3 by 3 cross-shaped kernel matrix and use it to dilate an image in OpenCV4Android.  In native C++ OpenCV, you'd do:

```
Mat kernel = (Mat_<int>(3,3) << 0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0);
dilate(image, image, kernel);
```

but how can I do the equivalent of the first line in Java?  A Mat cannot be treated like an array, and Java has no << operator.  There seems to be an OpenCV function called cvCreateStructuringElementEx which initializes Mats for use as kernels, but I can't find this function in OpenCV4Android.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never tried this but check if it works, at least this is the OpenCV4Android way to set a Structuring Element:

```
Mat kernel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_CROSS, new Size(3, 3));
```

Also, check out copyTo() method, it can receive a Mask:

```
src_mat.copyTo(dst_mat, mask);
```

Comment: I'm assuming that's good, although I've also got it to work by just sending in kernel = new Mat().

Comment: That will work but your kernel will be something else (some default) and not the 3x3 cross you mentioned.

Comment: Ah, got it.  I'll compare the two when I have time.